# Is there a API to scrape WhatsApp?

Tags: external-calls, api

Is there an API to scrape WhatsApp messages into Mathematica? Either doing it directly in Wolfram Language or using some python API and WL's `ExternalEvaluate`.

All I want is to get all my personal messages with individual or group messages into Mathematica so I can do some analytics. By the way I also want the timestamps and contact information of the poster of each message.

Comment: Doesn't WhatsApp require account validation via a SIM and a phone number? Perhaps you could somehow scrape them from the desktop version, but I don't know if the messages are still encrypted. Edit: There's a Business API: https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

Comment: There is a bar code that needs to be scanned for the desktop version to use the WhatsApp. But that is fine if there is a way to scrape the desktop version.

Comment: The easiest thing I can think of is to download your [personal data](https://www.pocket-lint.com/apps/news/whatsapp/144295-how-to-download-and-view-your-whatsapp-data-report)

Comment: "There is a bar code that needs to be scanned for the desktop version to use the WhatsApp." Yes, that's why I mentioned it, but I'm not sure how to scrape the desktop version.

Comment: @CarlLange It reads "Create a report of your WhatsApp account information and settings, which you can access or port to another app. This report does not include your messages."

Comment: @user13892 Ah, oversight on my part, sorry.

Comment: Although WhatsApp backs up all the data into GoogleDrive where in the Backups I can see the WhatsApp backup file but there is no option to download it onto the PC.

Comment: This channel seems to show a way to get the encrypted whatsapp backup file and its key out of the google drive and perhaps then I am assuming mathematica's cryptographic functionality be put to the test whether it can decrypt the database with the key. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZMEgcpD9vc (But the process seems scary - very hacker like).